# What's up with "Edit"

Tags: discussion, edits

When someone edits a posting, can they simply edit it?  Why do they have to mark it with "Edit:".  Authors of books don't do this.  Postings would read a lot smoother and look more permanent, if they didn't include "Edit:" all over the place.  If I want to see the edit history, it is available.